# How do I fix the Dragon Age 2 armor glitch?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In Dragon Age 2, there is a glitch where if you unequip and re-equip a shield, then it permanently increases your character's armor by 34 each time. Is there a way to fix or avoid this glitch? (The glitch occurs even if you just replace one shield with another shield, so you can't avoid the glitch just by never unequipping a shield if you want to upgrade the shield.) Is there a patch or something to fix this problem? I am using the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: Wait, you want to *avoid* permanently increasing your armor? Why?

Comment: @JSBangs > Some people prefer not to use exploits when gaming.  I'm the same way.

Comment: @Gnome, actually, me too. I just thought that the question was slightly ironic.

Comment: How in the world did this glitch get past QA?  Do game companies even *do* QA anymore!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have downloaded the latest patch and it fixes the issues.

Answer (score 6):

There is no fix at the moment. The only thing you can do is not equip any shields until you find the final upgrade. I didn't catch the glitch until the start of Act 2, so even with my tank's default shield, her armor rating was higher than it should have been.

Hoping for a patch because this is a game breaker.

Answer (score 4):

Dragon Age II patch 1.02 is now out - see [here](http://social.bioware.com/page/da2-patches).  This issue is not mentioned specifically, but may be one of the "minor" issues fixed.  May be worth a try.